# Nowadays do we need use extern "C" in c++ especially for c++ 11

Tags: c++, extern

I currently review and learn some github programs, and I fund in a hpp file:
there is **extern "C"** to cover all the c header file like **stdio.h**, **stdint.h** and so on.

```
extern "C"
{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <inttypes.h>
}
```

I also google how it works and I just wondering if we still need to do that. And **which way is better?**

1) to cover c header by extern "C";
2) just straightly include that c header files;